# Capture python standard output running through gunicorn

Tags: python, linux, terminal, flask, gunicorn

I've got a flask app that gives me output like
`127.0.0.1 - - [27/Nov/2012 20:56:33] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

How do I get this written to a file? I know I could run `python app.py > blah.log`, but how do I do the same thing with gunicorn running? Who is taking the output? I've noticed that looking at gunicorn's logs, it only has information about starting up and not about actual http requests.

Thanks!

Comment: Man, I think you write more this question when you just can read the official docs http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/configure.html

Comment: All the logs seem to be gunicorn specific, and not taking the output from the app that is being run though.

Comment: OK, I don't saw at once but how you setup logging in flask? Show your config.

Comment: Well, I have some logging that uses the python logger, but I've found that any fatal errors that happen in the application get put to standard out. I'm trying to catch everything that goes to standard out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out my problem. The logging page on flask is what I'm looking for:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/errorhandling/

What I missed in reading this is that the errors are logged to a file only in *production* mode.